# Unlimited gas for private blockchain?

Tags: truffle, out-of-gas

I'm working on something that is almost exclusively using a private blockchain.  We're using Ethereum because of its support for smart contracts.

While developing the contracts, I constantly run into issues with out-of-gas errors, especially in testing.  For instance, with truffle's Assert library, little by little I have to comment out more and more functions to avoid getting an error deploying my test contract.

I'm wondering first, whether there's a configuration where I could tell Ethereum (ganache, say) that gas just doesn't matter?  I tried setting its maximum gas extremely high, and even that didn't do the trick.

Second, is it possible that the issue isn't actually gas, but that's a red herring, and instead it's some inherent limitation on the size of a contract?

I tried asking about this on the truffle gitter, and got a bit of help, but mostly suggestions to raise the gas limit (only marginal change) and to remove Assert functions.

Comment: Since it is a private blockchain, you have the ability to allocate a "very high" amount of ether to an account on creation. For example, in geth's `genesis.json` file, there is the `alloc` object that contains initially defined accounts and their balances.
`"alloc": {
     "0x34ede9b637f0163ab0bb13ae9908bc25f7f6023b": {
         "balance": "88888888888888888888000000000000000000"
     },
      "0xbc4773626fed4d763e5d02e3aaef85be6ec67994": {
         "balance": "88888888888888888888000000000000000000"
      }, ...`

Comment: @AjoyBhatia, thanks.  It's not a problem with my account having too low a balance.  It seems to be a different problem.

I do wonder if the out of gas message is a red herring.  For instance, I saw another thread where someone said a require failed on contract creation, and he got that error.  Here, I don't have any such require calls, so I can't see why it'd die.  But what if "your contract is too big, and I don't care about your gas" is the real message it's trying to convey?

Answer (score 3):

Gas is a necessary feature in order for the main Ethereum network to be resilient against attacks (amongst other methods). I suggest checking out Quorum a lightweight Ethereum fork from JP Morgan, that does away with a gas **price** :)

Comment: Excellent!  I am aware why gas is needed for the main network.  I wondered if I would need to figure out how to do away with that limit.  If someone already has added that feature, definitely worth checking out.  Thanks.

Comment: Quorum does that all for ya :D along with some very cool additional features

Comment: Does it really do away with gas, or does it do away with gas pricing?  Two different things.

Comment: gas price good catch!

Comment: Ok... too bad! May not be as useful to me.